# rsync or rsync-like tool, without cygwin on windows xp machines

Tags: windows-xp, cygwin, rsync

Is there a tool with rsync functionality, or maybe rsync itself, without cygwin? that means, without the cygwin dll even. cygwin seems to have a horrible TCP latency problem, and is bugging down connections on a 100 mbps LAN to 35KB/s.

To be more specific, the tool should be able to operate over network, and has the functionality of the --delete and --hard-links parameters of rsync.

Comment: Have you tried Unison (I don't know if it has those features)

Comment: "Unison does not understand hard links." from their website... this is probably the single most important feature i require. otherwise, there are tons of applications that can do the job.

Comment: I often sync directorys between Windows and Linux. Now, I'm using `rsync -avh --delete ...` under cygwin. But the boring thing is file ownership and priviledges are often set incorrectly under Windows NTFS partition. After `rsync`, there are often bunch of problems under Windows. So, what is the best tool like `rsync` between Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSYS has an rsync [package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Extension/rsync/) available. MinGW/MSYS is similar to Cygwin, but it is an alternative. The rsync package does drag in a few dependencies if that's important, you can use [MinGW-get](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20120426/) to install it. Use the mingw-get-inst GUI to install MSYS, and then in the MSYS prompt use "mingw-get update" and "mingw-get install msys-rsync".